# GHC not generating dyn_hi

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a Linux machine with GHC 7.8.2 and cabal 1.20.0.1.

I'm trying to install `semigroups` and whenever I do, I get the dreaded error message about missing `dyn_hi` files.

```
/home/me/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.2/semigroups-0.14
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.18.1.3-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.2: Error: Could not find
module: Data.Semigroup with any suffix: ["dyn_hi"] in the search path:
["dist/build"]
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
semigroups-0.14 failed during the final install step. The exception was:
```

I've tried following the advice given [here](https://github.com/ekmett/comonad/issues/9) and [here](https://github.com/ekmett/comonad/issues/7). I've removed `.cabal/config`, `.ghc`, added `shared : True` and followed each step.But after multiple repetitions of these instructions I'm still getting the same errors.

Is there any other way to diagnose and fix these errors?

Comment: Is (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9176) anything to do with your problem?

Comment: @vivian It looks like it, though I don't really know how to confirm this. Since the bug isn't closed am I a bit screwed here?

Comment: If it is this bug then you'll have to wait for 7.8.3 or install HEAD once the bug is fixed.  You can add your cc on the bug Trac page.